# Is there any way to force windows updates to use the Temp folder instead of the root of C for installing updates?

Tags: windows, updates, temporary-files, patch

I would like to prevent them from even coming up if possible. I don't know why Windows doesn't use the %system root%\temp folder for these. :(

Looks like there have been a couple others asking about the same issue but the answer is just take ownership and delete, which would be fine if it were just 1 or 2 stations but I'm looking at possibly hundreds of them. Would there be a way to script a removal of these and force Windows into using the Temp folder?

Similar issue, 
[How do I delete left-over Windows Update folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/423766/how-do-i-delete-left-over-windows-update-folders)

Thanks,
Joel

Comment: keep in mind, these files are often there to provide uninstallation,

Comment: These are not the un-installation ones. These are in the root of C:\ and are supposed to be automatically removed after the patch or update is finished installing. Check out the known issues on this .net patch for what I'm referring to, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/951847/en-us